# including a python stub file for pybind11 module

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py, pybind11

I'm trying to package a module built with pybind11, which has a stub `.pyi` file associated with it.

The project structure is something like this:

```
my-pkg/
    setup.py
    my_pkg.pyi
    my_pkg/
        src/
            my_cpp_files.cpp
```

The `setup.py` file for the package looks something like this

```py
# setup.py

from glob import glob
from setuptools import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("my_pkg", sorted(glob("src/*.cpp")), include_dirs=['./'], cxx_std=17),
]

setup(
    name='my-pkg',
    description='This is my package',
    version='1.0.0',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

This successfully installs the `my_pkg` module into `site-packages` like so

```
site-packages/
    my_pkg-1.0.0.dist-info/
    my_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

However the `my_pkg.pyi` is not in included. I have manually copy and pasted the `my_pkg.pyi` stub file into `site-packages` directory to see if my IDE (vscode) recognises it, and it does.

Therefore I need a way for `setup.py` to install `my_pkg.pyi` into `site-packages`.

I have tried including the following lines into the `setup()` call without success:

1. `data_files=[('.', ['my_pkg.pyi'])]`
2. `package_data={'.': ['my_pkg.pyi']}`
3. `package_data={'my_pkg': ['my_pkg.pyi']}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is presently a way to install a `.pyi` file directly alongside the `.so` in the file structure, but you can exploit [PEP 561's stub-only packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#stub-only-packages) to create a separate package inside the repo containing just your stub, which will then be installed and recognised by compliant IDEs.

- Create a new directory inside your repo that must specifically called `my_pkg-stubs` (as per [PEP 561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#stub-only-packages))
- Rename `my_pkg.pyi` to `my_pkg-stubs/__init__.pyi`
- In your `setup.py`, add the `my_pkg-stubs` package, and ensure the `.pyi` file will be included in the distro:

```
...
    packages=[..., 'my_pkg-stubs'],
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={"my_pkg-stubs": ["*.pyi"]},
...
```

When `my_pkg` and `my_pkg-stubs` are both installed, a PEP561-compliant IDE will look in `my_pkg-stubs` for type hints, and automatically display them. I've verified this behaviour using Visual Studio Code on a [repo](https://github.com/ideoforms/signalflow/) that I've just applied this process to.